# JavaScript keydown in Chrome not capturing a single keypress that outputs multiple Unicode characters

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, unicode, keydown

I am working with Yiddish, for which some letters consist of two Unicode characters. For example, אַ consists of `U+05D0` + `U+05B7`. There are single code variants of these characters (eg. `U+FB2E` for אַ), but most keyboards take the former approach.

I'd like to capture input from a Yiddish keyboard using `keydown`, but I'm having trouble with these keys that output multiple Unicode characters. In particular, I'm using a simple code:

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (!event.metaKey) {
        console.log(event.key);
    }
});
```

See it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4acyehru/).

I'm on Windows, and on Firefox, I'm getting the expected result when I press אַ (which is the letter A on my keyboard, and outputs `U+05D0` `U+05B7`): namely, the console logs אַ. However, on Chrome (version 98), I get "Unidentified" as the output (although I get the expected result for any key that outputs a single Unicode character). The same thing happens on Edge. I don't have a Mac, but a friend tested for me and weirder things happened: it logged the `U+05B7` but not the `U+05D0`. Safari worked fine for him, though.

Any idea what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: Is the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) more helpful? Perhaps [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) can also be used here.